# Cannot explore my azure service fabric cluster

Tags: ssl, azure-service-fabric

On my team we are relatively new working on azure service fabric. We created a secure cluster using certificates. We are able to configure our cluster in the portal.azure.com. In the Security section we added an Admin Client in order to publish Service Fabric Applications in this cluster. I installed the client certificate in my certificate store and I was able to publish a Service Fabric application (apparently successfully).

My issue is that when I try to explore our cluster I receive an authorization denial through an http 403 forbidden error. So I cannot explore our cluster from any browser. I suspect that I have a problem with the certificates but I have not been able to resolve it.

Update:
I am seeing this error in the chrome developer console: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Client certificate required)

May be somebody had or has the same problem.

Comment: Did you add the cert into the my/personal store of the machine that runs the browser? And does it have the private key too? And did you select that one when being challenged by the browser?

Comment: I added the cert into the my/personal in CurrentUser store in my machine, where I am running the browser. It has the private key but the browser is not giving to me the option to select that certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved. My issue was that I was trying to use a wrong certificate. The certificate I had was for Server Authentication so Chrome (or any browser) was not able to give the option of picking it. I generate a new certificate for client authentication. I added the new certificate as Admin Client in the Security section of the cluster in azure, as I had done with the wrong one before. I restarted my pc and then chrome gave the option to pick the correct certificate. The authentication was successful and I am able to explore the cluster.